# Simple Rails functional test fails due to apparent authentication issues (Rails 2.3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, activerecord, rake

I am testing an existent Rails test suite by creating a new functional test, but am seeing the following test failures that just do not make sense. Note that I have done extensive research here and across the interwebs, so I'm posting this as a last resort:

```
    Justins-MacBook-Pro-4:custserv-web_rake justinfox$ rake test    
    TEST=test/functional/auth_zones_controller_test.rb --trace 
    rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
    ** Invoke test (first_time)
    ** Execute test
    ** Invoke test:units (first_time)
    ** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
    ** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
    ** Invoke environment (first_time)
    ** Execute environment

          *******************************************************************
          * config.breakpoint_server has been deprecated and has no effect. *
          *******************************************************************

    ** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
    ** Execute db:test:prepare
    ** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
    ** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
    ** Invoke environment 
    ** Execute db:test:purge
    ** Execute db:test:load
    ** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
    ** Invoke environment 
    ** Execute db:schema:load
    ** Execute test:units
    /Users/justinfox/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.5.5/bin/jruby -I"lib:test" -
    I"/Users/justinfox/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.5@rails2.3.2/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib" 
    "/Users/justinfox/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.5@rails2.3.2/gems/rake-
    0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/functional/auth_zones_controller_test.rb" 
    /Users/justinfox/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.5@rails2.3.2/gems/rails-
    2.3.2/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:99:Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is 
    deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement

          *******************************************************************
          * config.breakpoint_server has been deprecated and has no effect. *
          *******************************************************************

    /Users/justinfox/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.5@rails2.3.2/gems/ruby-debug-base-0.10.3.2-
   java/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:214 warning: tracing (e.g. set_trace_func) will not capture all 
   events without --debug flag
    Loaded suite /Users/justinfox/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.5@rails2.3.2/gems/rake-
   0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
      Started
      access_denied params: --- !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess 
      user: quentin
      action: login_as
      controller: auth_zones
      in store location for /auth_zones/login_as?user=quentin
      Eaccess_denied params: --- !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess 
      user: quentin
      action: login_as
      controller: auth_zones
      in store location for /auth_zones/login_as?user=quentin
      access_denied params: --- !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess 
      user: quentin
      action: index
      controller: auth_zones
      in store location for /auth_zones/login_as?user=quentin
      F
      Finished in 0.245 seconds.

        1) Error:
      test_should_delete_auth_zone(AuthZonesControllerTest):
      TypeError: nil is not a string
          lib/authenticated_test_helper.rb:43:in `assert_difference'
          test/functional/auth_zones_controller_test.rb:19:in `test_should_delete_auth_zone'

        2) Failure:
      test_should_get_index(AuthZonesControllerTest) [test/functional/auth_zones_controller_test.rb:14]:
      <nil> expected to not be nil.

      2 tests, 2 assertions, 1 failures, 1 errors
      Errors running test:units, test:functionals, and test:integration!
```

Following are all relevant files:

auth_zone_controller_test.rb

```
  require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper'
  require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../app/controllers/account_controller'
  require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../app/controllers/auth_zones_controller'

  class AuthZonesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    include AuthenticatedTestHelper

    fixtures :auth_zone, :users

    test "should get index" do
      post :login_as, :user => 'quentin'
      get :index
      assert_response :redirect
      assert_not_nil assigns(:auth_zones)
    end

    test "should delete auth zone" do
      post :login_as, :user => 'quentin'
      assert_difference 'AuthZone.count' do
        delete :delete_auth_zone, :id => auth_zone(:one).param
      end
      assert_response :redirect
    end

  end
```

account_controller.rb

```
  def login
   logger.info("session: #{session.to_yaml}")
    if request.post?
      logger.info("in account login (post); session[:return_to] = #{session[:return_to]}")
      self.current_user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
      if logged_in?
        if current_user.isCustomerType()
          reset_session
        end
        redirect_back_or_default(url_for(:controller => :home, :action => :index))
        #redirect_to :controller => :home, :action => :index
      else
        flash[:heading] = "Login Error"
        flash[:notice] = "The email address and password do not match a SAM Connect account.<br/>
        <br/>Please try again or contact a SAMC Administrator."
        redirect_to :action => :login
        return
      end
    elsif request.get?
      logger.info("in account login (get); session[:return_to] = #{session[:return_to]}")
      if logged_in?
        session[:return_to] = nil
        redirect_to(:controller => :home, :action => :index)
      end
    end    
  end
```

Relevant methods in auth_zone_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @auth_zones = AuthZone.find(:all)
  end

  # Delete an auth zone
  def delete_auth_zone
    auth_zone_code = AuthZone.find(params[:id]).code
    AuthZone.destroy(params[:id])
    flash[:notice] = auth_zone_code + " Auth Zone has been deleted"
    redirect_to(:action => :index)
  end
```

auth_zone.yml

```
    test_zone_1:
      id: 1
      created_at: <%= 2.days.ago.to_s :db %>
      updated_at: <%= 1.days.ago.to_s :db %>
      code: TESTZONE1
      desc: "Test Zone 1"
      url: "https://testzone1.com"

    test_zone_2:
      id: 2
      created_at: <%= 2.days.ago.to_s :db %>
      updated_at: <%= 1.days.ago.to_s :db %>
      code: TESTZONE2
      desc: "Test Zone 2"
      url: "https://testzone2.com"
```

users.yml (fixture)

```
    quentin:
      id: 1
      email: quentin@example.com
      salt: 7e3041ebc2fc05a40c60028e2c4901a81035d3cd
      crypted_password: 00742970dc9e6319f8019fd54864d3ea740f04b1 # test
      #crypted_password: "ce2/iFrNtQ8=\n" # quentin, use only if you're using 2-way encryption
      created_at: <%= 5.days.ago.to_s :db %>
      # activated_at: <%= 5.days.ago.to_s :db %> # only if you're activating new signups
    aaron:
      id: 2
      email: aaron@example.com
      salt: 7e3041ebc2fc05a40c60028e2c4901a81035d3cd
      crypted_password: 00742970dc9e6319f8019fd54864d3ea740f04b1 # test
      # activation_code: aaronscode # only if you're activating new signups
      created_at: <%= 1.days.ago.to_s :db %>
```

authenticated_system.rb::access_denied()

```
   def access_denied
      puts "access_denied params: #{params.to_yaml}"
      respond_to do |accepts|
        accepts.html do
          store_location
          flash[:notice] = logged_in? ? "Access Denied" : "Access Denied. Please Login."
          redirect_to :controller => :account, :action => :login
        end
        accepts.xml do
          headers["Status"]           = "Unauthorized"
          headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = %(Basic realm="Web Password")
          render :text => "Could't authenticate you", :status => '401 Unauthorized'
        end
      end
      logger.info("authenticated_system access_denied; session[:return_to] = #   
      {session[:return_to]}")
      false
    end
```

Gem list:

```
            *** LOCAL GEMS ***

            actionmailer (2.3.2)
            actionpack (2.3.2)
            activerecord (2.3.2)
            activerecord-jdbc-adapter (0.9.2)
            activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (0.9.2)
            activeresource (2.3.2)
            activesupport (2.3.2)
            columnize (0.3.1)
            fastercsv (1.4.0)
            hpricot (0.8.2)
            httpclient (2.1.4)
            jdbc-mysql (5.0.4)
            jruby-openssl (0.5)
            mislav-will_paginate (2.3.11)
            rack (1.0.0)
            rails (2.3.2)
            rails_sql_views (0.8.0)
            rake (0.8.7)
            rspec (1.2.9)
            ruby-debug (0.10.3)
            ruby-debug-base (0.10.3.2)
            rubygems-update (1.8.15)
            rubyzip (0.9.1)
            soap4r (1.5.8)
            sources (0.0.1)
            will_paginate (2.2.2)
```

Comment: The `TypeError: nil is not a string` message is being thrown from line number 43 of `lib/authenticated_test_helper.rb`; did you check what's in that line?

Comment: @PrakashMurthy Thank you, I am addressing that. Do you have an idea about the second error?

`2) Failure:
      test_should_get_index(AuthZonesControllerTest)[test/functional/auth_zones_controller_test.rb:14]:
      <nil> expected to not be nil.`

Comment: Also, I think the root cause here is the access_denied errors here:

        `access_denied params: --- !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess 
        action: delete_auth_zone
        id: "1"
        controller: auth_zones
        in store location for /auth_zones/delete_auth_zone/1
        Faccess_denied params: --- !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess 
        action: index
        controller: auth_zones
        in store location for /auth_zones`

I've edited my post above to include the access_denied method from /lib/authenticated_system.rb

Comment: @JustinFox Can you add the `test.log` output from this test?

Comment: @ScottJShea Unfortunately, the tests seem to not be logging anywhere (including test.log). Can you advise on this issue?